# Custom maps in Leaflet with MapTiler and geoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson, maptiler

In an app that I am currently developing I have downloadable "modules" that alter the look & feel of the app.  As part of that experience I also need to adapt the look & feel of the maps that I am showing in the app - I should mention that the maps are for a very limited geographic area.  I am thinking of doing this as follows

- Use the Leaflet geoJSON custom layer.  If I understand right this layer has a native understanding of geoJSON and also offers the ability to style the lines, polygons etc that are drawn on-the-fly via supplied functions
- Have multiple sets of custom map imagery (buildings, water features etc) drawn up for me and convert them into map tiles with MapTiler for delivery from our own CDN
- Show the map imagery in one geoJSON layer
- show streets etc in a second geoJSON layer and use exported OSM streets geoJSON data for the purpose with supplied functions used to alter the rendering of the streets and their names

Although I have been using Leaflet for years, I have never done this sort of thing before.  Is the thing feasible at all?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible. But since GIS SE is intended for focused question, this question risks of being closed as needing more focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MapTiler Desktop https://www.maptiler.com/desktop/ to turn your imagery (PNG/JPG/TIFF) into tiles you also receive a sample Leaflet viewer as HTML/JS code for how to display it. It is generated together with the map tiles.

Adding additional GeoJSON layers on top should be quite straightforward with Leaflet.

Just follow video tutorial at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxa7PPqp6Fc&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PUNP4DtIshALDogSURIlYB&index=5&ab_channel=MapTiler